# Wrinting a program using loop only

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was tasked with creating a program that finds all positive integers within a defined range. Currently I'm in school so I am limited to only using loops and functions to make it work (Also note that I have just started learning to use functions.

I've uploaded the picture of it.

my problem lies when I run it instead of printing only the positive values it also prints out 10 000 blank lines. I want that to not be the case.
I think it has something to do with the second else statement.

[image]

Comment: Don't post a picture of your code. Instead, copy and paste the code and be sure to format it so other people can copy it and run it. Read the guidelines here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Your else is printing 'z' but when you return 'z' you're also printing it. Also I'm not sure I understand the objective of the program. If you want to find all the positive integers within a range you can just start from one end and decrement/increment until you reach the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getDivisors(number):
    divList = []
    for x in range(1,number):
        if number % x == 0:
            divList.append(x)
    return divList

def isPerfectNumber(divList,number):
    if sum(divList) == number:
        return True
    else:
        return False

for x in range(2,10001):
    divList = getDivisors(x)
    if isPerfectNumber(divList,x):
        print(x,divList)
```

Looks like that code works.  I also had it print out the divison list so you can check verify the numbers for yourself.

Here is my output:

6 [1, 2, 3]

28 [1, 2, 4, 7, 14]

496 [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248]

8128 [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 127, 254, 508, 1016, 2032, 4064]

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate the help. I just started programming, so i might seem a bit floopy, but i hope with time i'll become better.